# Solving a rational equation with multiple and nested fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, fractions, rational-functions

> This is the equation to solve: $\dfrac{\dfrac{x+\dfrac{1}{2}} {\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x}{3}}}{\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{x}{5}}=3$

What I did:

$x+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{2x+1}{2}$

$\dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{2x+3}{6}$

$\dfrac{x}{5}+\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{4x+5}{20}$

$\dfrac{2x+1}{2}\div \dfrac{2x+3}{6} = \dfrac{2x+1}{2}\times \dfrac{6}{2x+3}=   \dfrac{6x+3}{2x+3}$

$\dfrac{6x+3}{2x+3}\div\dfrac{4x+5}{20}=\dfrac{6x+3}{2x+3}\times\dfrac{20}{4x+5}=3$

$\implies\dfrac{120x+60}{(2x+3)(4x+5)}=3$

I know how to solve the equation. But right now I tried several times and I got wrong answers.

So I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: You have a minor error in your second-to-last line, where $4x+5$ magically became $4x+20$.

Comment: Be sure to clarify which division has priority.  Note that $(a\div b)\div c\ne a\div (b\div c)$

Comment: @  Brian Tung:Edited. Thank you

Comment: @  paw88789: I submitted the equation as I had it.

Comment: To simplify the expression abit, use $y=0.5$.

Comment: Another approach: $$3 = 3\times\frac{(2x+3)(4x+5)}{(2x+3)(4x+5)}$$ Now we can compare two fractions with common denominators.

Comment: @ Rafiq - You stated to paw88789 that "I [you] submitted the equation as I [you] had it."  That equation cannot be worked out, because the expression on the left-hand side of the equals sign is ambiguous.  One cannot tell which fraction is being divided into which fraction.  Grouping symbols such as larger parentheses added around either the top two fractions, or the bottom two fractions, whichever the case may be. will correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, essentially,

$$
\frac{120x+60}{(2x+3)(4x+5)} = 3
$$

Multiply both sides by $(2x+3)(4x+5)$ to get

$$
120x+60 = 3(2x+3)(4x+5) = 24x^2+66x+45
$$

Subtract $120x+60$ from both sides to get

$$
24x^2-54x-15 = 0
$$

Divide both sides by $3$ to get

$$
8x^2-18x-5 = 0
$$

which factors as

$$
(4x+1)(2x-5) = 0
$$

to yield $x = -1/4$ or $5/2$.  (Or, you can use the quadratic formula.)

Comment: @ Brian Tung - Again, I am mentioning that what you did is not a solution, because the presented problem has an ambiguous expression that has not been resolved  From a comment above:  "That equation cannot be worked out, because the expression on the left-hand side of the equals sign is ambiguous. One cannot tell which fraction is being divided into which fraction. Grouping symbols such as larger parentheses added around either the top two fractions, or the bottom two fractions, whichever the case may be. will correct it."

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\frac{\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{3}}}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{5}}=3$$
$$\frac{\frac{3(2x+1)}{(2x+3)}}{\frac{4x+5}{20}}=3$$
$$\frac{60(2x+1)}{(2x+3)(4x+5)}=3$$
$$8x^2-18x-5=0$$
$$x=\frac{18\pm\sqrt{(-18)^2-4(8)(-5)}}{2(8)}$$
$$x=\frac{18\pm22}{16}$$ $$x=\frac{5}{2}$$ or $$ x=-\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { \frac { 2x+1 }{ \frac { 2 }{ \frac { 3+2x }{ 6 }  }  }  }{ \frac { 5+4x }{ 20 }  } =3\quad \Rightarrow \frac { \frac { 2x+1 }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { 6 }{ 2x+3 }  }{ \frac { 5+4x }{ 20 }  } =3\quad \Rightarrow \frac { \frac { 2x+1 }{ 2x+3 }  }{ \frac { 5+4x }{ 20 }  } =1\Rightarrow \frac { 2x+1 }{ 2x+3 } =\frac { 5+4x }{ 20 } \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow 8{ x }^{ 2 }-18x-5=0\Rightarrow x=\frac { 9\pm 11 }{ 8 } $$

Comment: @Strants: I don't accept that you add the parenthesis, because the original given equation  hadn't them. So please, delete them.

Comment: @Strants:Deleted.